# Visual Studio Build Website Without ASP.NET

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm working on a website (professionally) that uses a C# server back-end, and our front-end is written in Typescript. Because we're using Microsoft languages, it made sense to develop using Visual Studio, however, because our back-end is C#, we have no need of ASP.NET, but because we're using Typescript we still want to "build" the website. Our solution is laid out with a bunch of C# projects which all build and run fine, and one Website project name "ExpressWeb" that contains all of the scripting, markup and styling that make up the front-end.

We're running the build tasks through the TaskRunner plugin using gulp.js, so basically we just want it to run a gulp task on the "After Build" hook. That way, when a dev wants to build everything (we all work on both the back-end and front-end), they just use Visual Studio's build command.

The problem we're having is that whenever we'd attempt to build the website, visual studio would try to throw it at the ASP.NET compiler. Since the deploy machine only uses command-line build tools, we were able to circumvent this by removing literally everything in the `ProjectSection`, so it would see there was nothing to do, and then run the gulp tasks manually. To get the build-hooks running for the developers, however, we'd still like to just be able to hit "Build" and then everything builds if need be. When you build from visual studio, it generates a new .sln file, and it causes the `ProjectSection` to look like this:

```
ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
    TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_56894"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "ExpressWeb\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_56894\"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Debug.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "True"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.VirtualPath = "/localhost_56894"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.PhysicalPath = "ExpressWeb\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.TargetPath = "PrecompiledWeb\localhost_56894\"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Updateable = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.ForceOverwrite = "true"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.FixedNames = "false"
    Release.AspNetCompiler.Debug = "False"
    VWDPort = "56894"
    SlnRelativePath = "ExpressWeb\"
EndProjectSection
```

when what was working looked like this:

```
ProjectSection(WebsiteProperties) = preProject
    TargetFrameworkMoniker = ".NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5"
    SlnRelativePath = "ExpressWeb\"
EndProjectSection
```

Is there some way I can build a website without using ASP.NET, or failing that, some way to stop visual studio from overwriting this specific project's build instructions in the solution file without making the whole thing immutable?